# Как получить значение между слов, обработать его и заменить

Tags: php

Есть такая строка:

```
$string = 'текст текст уже 10 минут текст текст';
```

мне нужно получить значение между словами **уже** и **минут**

Далее полученное значение записать в переменную `$temp` , выполнить некоторые операции, например:

```
$new = $temp+5;
```

и в `$string` заменить исходное полученное значение переменной `$new`

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как самое очевидное:

```
$string = 'текст текст уже 10 минут текст текст';

$result = preg_replace_callback('#(?<=уже )(.*)(?= минут)#Uiu', function($value) {
    $value[1] = $value[1] + 5;
    return $value[1];
}, $string);

echo $result;
```

Если внутри `function` нужно использовать внешние параметры, то используем `use`

Comment: лучше использовать позитивные просмотры назад и вперед, тогда в соответствии останется только само значение, и его же потребуется вернуть, без всяких там `уже/минут`

Comment: @teran подправиль, так правильнее будет ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: вроде того, можете еще сократить до`return $value[1] + 5` :)

Comment: @teran эт я в курсе, сделал осознано чтобы показать автору наглядно манипуляции и действия с тем числом. Просто если человек не силен то `return $value[1] + 5` может смутить...

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с оптимизированным по скорости pcre-шаблоном:

```
$string = 'текст текст уже 10 минут текст текст';

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '~уже\h\K.+(?=\hминут)~i',
    function($temp) { return $temp[0] + 5; },
    $string
);

echo $string;
```

Результат:

```
текст текст уже 15 минут текст текст
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'текст текст уже 10 минут текст текст';

$int = (int) filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$string = str_replace($int, $int+5, $string);

echo $string;
```

Comment: и что будет, если какое-либо число будет в начале строки?

Comment: А в вопросе про это ничего не сказано. Есть строка, есть задание. Всё.

Comment: сказано, заменить между конкретными словами.

Comment: А здесь что-то делается не так? Значение заменяется. Решать автору, какой из ответов ему больше по душе.

Comment: очевидно, что вместо "текст текст" может быть произвольный текст,в том числе включающий цифры.

Comment: _есть строка, есть задание_ - верно. Только вы решаете какое-то другое задание, а не то, которое в вопросе.

Comment: @Эникейщик, **получить значение между словами** - получено, **произвести операцию** - произведено, **сохранить новое значение** - сохранено. Я действовал согласно вопросу, а не старался его дополнить. А если в строке имеются другие числа, то автор сам мне сделает замечание и тогда мне придется изменить ответ. Если дополнять вопрос, то можно сказать, что автор слова **минут** и **уже** может написать с ошибкой и тогда сторонний ответ не сработает.

Comment: @teran, дак и в случае с регуляркой выше, если будет вначале строки `текст текст 10 минут уже текст текст` не сработает, а вот в этом случае, сработает =)

Comment: `...что автор слова минут и уже может написать с ошибкой и тогда сторонний ответ не сработает...` - действительно, как я об этом не подумал... Раз уж меня приписали сюда, позволю высказать свое мнение: различие вашего ответа от моего в **гибкости**... Ваш пример решает в лоб **только** текущий пример и все. Будь там дробное число (между словами) либо вообще не число, а строка - ваш метод ломается, не говоря уже о рисках иметь число раньше необходимого...

Comment: Какая конкретно строчка вашего решения ищет число между словами "уже" и "минут", а не между любыми другими словами? Вы не дополнили вопрос, а упростили его. PS. Если написать слова "минут" и "уже" с ошибкой, то это будут другие слова и другой ответ всё так же останется рабочим.

Comment: `текст текст 10 текст текст` - ваш код выдаст `10` однако, он не находится между словами `уже` и `минут`. `5 уже 10 минут` - ваш код тоже не сработает, однако вы говорите пусть автор уточняет вопрос, тогда всю проблему можно вообще решить так: `mb_substr($string, 0, 16) . (mb_substr($string, 16, 2) + 5) . mb_substr($string, 18, 18)` - Между тегами нашел? - нашел. операцию сделал? сделал. А то что там может быть другой текст - пусть автор грамотно задает вопросы и присылает примеры всех текстов или пишет генератор текстов.

Comment: @Manitikyl, не ну это вы уже палку перегнули. В моем примере текст может меняться. Я не кричу, что мой ответ лучший. Но согласитесь, он имеет хоть малейшее право на жизнь, если в тексте нет других чисел. Поэтому всё зависит от задач автора.

Comment: @ДенисНебесный `текст может меняться` - тут вы забыли указать главное: что этот текст не должен содержать цифр... Если в тексте нет других чисел - право на жизнь возможно и есть.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем по вопросу, но в тему: почему не разделить логику просчёта и вывод данных? Где-нить в сессии таскайте за собой числовое значение.

```
$_SESSION['num'] = 5; // initial

$num = $_SESSION['num'] + 5; // processing
$_SESSION['num'] = 5; // following

$string = 'текст текст уже %s минут текст текст';
$output = sprintf($string, $num);

echo $output;
```

Comment: Где вы тут увидели сессии? =))) Не вводите ТС в заблуждение

Comment: Я тут увидел php и альтернативное решение задачи. И, обратите внимание, даже написал "Не совсем по вопросу..."

Comment: @KirillKorushkin знаете, в чём принципиальная разница между вопросом топик стартера, и вашим ответом? -- ему нужно *найти* значение, а у вас значение константно, и всё, что выполняет ваш код, это *подстановку* константного значения. Поэтому "не является ответом" :)

Comment: Благодарю вас за мнение. Я это ценю.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin кстати, для чисел корректнее использовать описатель `d` : `'текст текст уже %d минут текст текст'`

Comment: Я думаю с положительными натуральными числами это не так принципиально. Однако можете исправить ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ищем всё что лежит до искомого числа, само число и всё что после него. Меняем значение и склеиваем строку из тех же самых кусков:

```
$string = 'текст текст уже 10 минут текст текст';

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '/' .
        '(?<before>\bуже\s+)' .
        '(?<minutes>\d+)' .
        '(?<after>\s+минут\b)' .
    '/isu',
    function ($matches) {
        $minutes = (int) $matches['minutes'];
        $minutes = $minutes * 2 + 10;
        return $matches['before'] . $minutes . $matches['after'];
    },
    $string
);

// string(64) "текст текст уже 30 минут текст текст"
var_dump($string);
```